# Variadic template class - variadic member function

Tags: c++, templates

I am working on project that requires generic cache for multiple stored classes. My base class looks like this:

```
template<typename ... Types>
class VarCache{
    template<typename T>
    using item_type = shared_ptr<holder<T>>;
    template<typename T>
    using map_type = map<int64_t,item_type <T>>;
public:
    std::tuple<map_type<Types>...> caches;
};
```

I need to write function that would accept no arguments, but by calling it on cache object, it would iteratively traverse all stored map variants, and perfrom action(removing unneeded items).

Example:

I have `VarCache<A,B,C> cache` and method `prune<T>();` where `T` is one of `A,B,C`

and by calling `cache.prune_all_variants();` I want cache to perform

```
prune<A>();
prune<B>();
prune<C>();
```

is this possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few tricks you can use to call a function for each element of a parameter pack. Here's one option:

```
void prune_all_variants() {
    (void)std::initializer_list<int> {
        (prune<Types>(), 0)...  
    };
}
```

In C++17, this can be simplified to the following using [fold expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold):

```
void prune_all_variants() {
    (prune<Types>(), ...);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use:

```
void prune_all_variants()
{
    int dummy[] = {0, (prune<Types>(), void(), 0)...};
    static_cast<void>(dummy); // avoid warning for unused variable.
}
```

or with fold expression in C++17:

```
void prune_all_variants() {
    (static_cast<void>(prune<Types>()), ...);
}
```